# Convert integer to character int j2me

Tags: java-me

I want to convert the integer into char.

Example:-

```
char c;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    system.out.println(" char==="+c);
}
```

I want to print the c as 0,1,2,3,4.....
I had tried :-

```
c=(char)i; --gives error
c=97-i; -----gives a,b,c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wrapper classes.

```
c = new Integer(i).toString().charAt(0);
```

by the way, you can also use this :

```
c = (char)(i + 48);
```

Comment: That's a pretty roundabout way to do it.

Comment: Or `c = Integer.toString(i).charAt(0);`, or `c = (char)(i+(int)'0');`

Comment: bingo .. java is pretty flexible for a compiled language :)

Answer (score -1):

`Character.forDigit()`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

Comment: j2me doesn't have this class I guess

Comment: Sorry didn't understand question at first without the right code formatting.

Comment: @Jigar: j2me doesn't have a java.lang class??!

Comment: @truthreality it has java.lang 'package' of course. But Wrapper classes (amogst others) come with lesser methods.