# How to convert ASCII code (0-255) to its corresponding character?

Tags: java, ascii

How can I convert, in Java, the ASCII code (which is an integer from [0, 255] range) to its corresponding ASCII character?

For example:

```
65  -> "A"
102 -> "f"
```

Comment: this is not a duplicate as mentioned above. This is not conversion from integer but from char (ascii)

Comment: *Not* a duplicate of "How to convert from int to String?"... anyway, FWIW, ASCII is only 7-bits with values [0, 127] ;-)

Comment: @phooji I think that that post sais how to convert 1->"1" etc'

Comment: @pst - it's extended ASII ;-)

Comment: @Belgi: Perhaps this is a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833709/converting-int-to-char-in-java .

Comment: @Belgi - you'll need to explicitly state your encoding if you want to correctly transcode values 128-255. The term "extended ASCII" is not meaningful.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

[`Character.toString ((char) i);`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29)

Comment: For MIDP 2 / CLDC 1.1 based platforms (which don't have `Character.toString(char)`, http://stackoverflow.com/a/6210938/923560 provides additional solutions.

Comment: What is the reason for the `(char)` designation?  In other words, why can't I just put `Character.toString(i);` ? (Java noob)

Comment: Note that this will not work for the `Integer` type, you will get a "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Character" error. Add a cast to `int` first, e.g.:

`Character.toString((char)(int)myInteger);`

Comment: The `i` values (0-255) would be from the ISO-8859-1 character set. (The question asker declined to identify which "extended ASCII" [vague term] was wanted, except by accepting this answer.)

Answer (score 67):

`System.out.println((char)65);`
would print "A"

Comment: REPL tip: If you happen to be using JShell (Java 9) you can omit the System.out. Just type `(char) 65` to find out what character it is.

Comment: Question is not about printing but converting.

Answer (score 38):

[`String.valueOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%5b%5d%29)`(`[`Character.toChars(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars%28int%29)`)`

Assuming the integer is, as you say, between 0 and 255, you'll get an array with a single character back from `Character.toChars`, which will become a single-character string when passed to `String.valueOf`.

Using `Character.toChars` is preferable to methods involving a cast from `int` to `char` (i.e. `(char) i`) for a number of reasons, including that `Character.toChars` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if you fail to properly validate the integer while the cast will swallow the error (per the [narrowing primitive conversions specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.3)), potentially giving an output other than what you intended.

Comment: Assuming that the integer is in the range 0 to 255 (as you state that you do ... and as the question specifies), it is unnecessary and suboptimal to use `toChars`.

Comment: You're completely correct that something like `Character.toString((char) i)` is faster than `String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i))`. Running a quick benchmark of converting 1,000,000 random integers in the given range (100 times, to be safe) on my machine gives an average time of 153.07 nanoseconds vs. 862.39 nanoseconds. However, in any interesting application, there will be far more important things to optimize. The added value of the safe, deterministic handling and ease of expanding outside the [0,255] range should it be required outweighs the minor performance hit.

Answer (score 15):

```
int number = 65;
char c = (char)number;
```

it is a simple solution

Answer (score 7):

```
    new String(new char[] { 65 })
```

You will end up with a string of length one, whose single character has the (ASCII) code 65. In Java chars are numeric data types.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way of doing the same:

Type cast integer to character, let `int n` be the integer,
then:

```
Char c=(char)n;
System.out.print(c)//char c will store the converted value.
```

Answer (score 1):

One can iterate from a to z like this

```
int asciiForLowerA = 97;
int asciiForLowerZ = 122;
for(int asciiCode = asciiForLowerA; asciiCode <= asciiForLowerZ; asciiCode++){
    search(sCurrentLine, searchKey + Character.toString ((char) asciiCode));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " -> " + (char) i);
    }

    char lowercase = 'f';
    int offset = (int) 'a' - (int) 'A';
    char uppercase = (char) ((int) lowercase - offset);
    System.out.println("The uppercase letter is " + uppercase);

    String numberString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter an ASCII code:",
            "ASCII conversion", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    int code = (int) numberString.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("The character for ASCII code "
            + code + " is " + (char) code);
```

Comment: Explain your answer please

Answer (score -1):

This is an example, which shows that by converting an int to char, one can determine the corresponding character to an ASCII code.

```
public class sample6
{
    public static void main(String... asf)
    {

        for(int i =0; i<256; i++)
        {
            System.out.println( i + ". " + (char)i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

upper answer only near solving the Problem. heres your answer:

Integer.decode(Character.toString(char c));