# Count char in Java excluding ascii 32

Tags: java, count, char

My problem is this the previous code words.lenght() is counting all the characters including space. What i want to do is count all characters excluding space which is ascii 32.

```
public static void main (String args[]){


        String words = "kickflip in the face yo!";
        int ff = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<=words.length(); i++){

            if(words.charAt(i) == (char) 32)
                continue;


            ff++;

        }

        System.out.print(ff);
```

Comment: [`Character.isSpace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSpaceChar(char))?  How about `words.replace(" ", "").length()`?

Comment: That looks fine. What's your problem?

Comment: it says Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 17
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at TestKlass.main(TestKlass.java:15)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7694012/2055998

Comment: @tinker101, it won't be at 17 with that string, it'll be at 24. In any case, both answers (to date), mine included, point out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `<=` in the `for` line where you should use `<` (resulting in an exception when you try to grab the character at index 24), and the missing closing brace (which I assume is just a typo), that code should work fine.

With those problems fixed, it gives you the correct value of `20`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        String words = "kickflip in the face yo!";
        int ff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
            if (words.charAt(i) != ' ')
                ff++;
        System.out.print(ff);
    }
}
```

You'll notice I've made two other small mods which make the code better (in my opinion).

The first is to use `' '` rather than `(char)32`, the second is to slightly restructure the counting bit so you don't need `continue`.

There are no doubt other improvements that could be made but they'd tend to get away from the beginner level.