# printing unique char and their occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am new to `java` and programming too. I have given an assignment to count the occurrence of unique character. I have to use only
array. I have do the flowing code -

```
public class InsertChar{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] charArray = new int[1000];
        char[] testCharArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'd', 'a'};

        for(int each : testCharArray){

            if(charArray[each]==0){
                charArray[each]=1;
            }else{
                ++charArray[each];
            }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            if(charArray[i]!=0){
                System.out.println( i +": "+ charArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For the `testCharArray` the output should be -

```
a: 4
b: 1
c: 2
d: 2
x: 2
```

But it gives me the following outpu -

```
97: 4
98: 1
99: 2
100: 2
120: 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `testCharArray` is an array of int. You have stored char in it. So you have to cast character to int.
You have to make a change at your last for loop -

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    if(charArray[i]!=0){
        System.out.println( (char)i +": "+ charArray[i]); //cast int to char.
    }
}
```

This casting make the int to char. Each character have an int value. For example -

'a' has 97 as it's `int` value
'b' has 98 as it's `int` value

Answer (score 3):

`i` is `int`, so you are printing the integer value of each `char`. You have to cast it to `char` in order to see the characters.

change

```
System.out.println( i +": "+ charArray[i]);
```

to

```
System.out.println( (char)i +": "+ charArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the index as an `int`. Try casting it to a `char` before printing it:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    if (charArray[i]!=0){
        System.out.println( ((char) i) +": "+ charArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program is printing `ascii` representation of characters. You just need to convert the `acsii` numbers to chars.

```
public class InsertChar{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] charArray = new int[1000];
        char[] testCharArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'x', 'a', 'd', 'a'};

        for(int each : testCharArray){

            if(charArray[each]==0){
                charArray[each]=1;
            }else{
                ++charArray[each];
            }

        }

        for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            if(charArray[i]!=0){
                System.out.println( **(char)**i +": "+ charArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This should work.

Further reading:

[How to convert ASCII code (0-255) to a String of the associated character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-a-string-of-the-associated-character)

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the `ASCII` `int` representation of each `char`. You have to convert them to `char`  by casting -

```
System.out.println( (char)i +": "+ charArray[i]);
```