# How would I convert an integer value into an ASCII Character value in Java

Tags: java

I have the code to write a program that people enter a decimal value and i have to convert it to Hex, Octal, Binary, and Character values. Everything but Character value will print out in java eclipse. Simple program but confused.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert ASCII code (0-255) to a String of the associated character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-a-string-of-the-associated-character)

Comment: Confused with what? We're not mind readers.

Comment: You would start by doing some research on this topic. Do you really, seriously think that you are the very first person in the world who wants to do something like that? And that nobody else ever documented how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int i=65;
System.out.println((char)i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer to string, and take it digit by digit.

Then add 48 or (30 Hex) to each digit to get its ASCII code.

e.g. int(5) will be (5 + 48) = 53

e.g. int(16) will be (6 + 48) = 54, and (1 + 48) = 49

I hope this solves it.