# how decode ascii code from json

Tags: java, android, ascii, decode

I received a json file with ascii code in middle, for example:

`&#226;mbito da Comemora&#231;&#227;o do Dia de S&#227;o Valentim, 14 de fevereiro.`

How decode this to special chars in java.

Thanks you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-a-string-of-the-associated-character

Comment: "I received a json file with ascii code in middle" -- actually, you received a JSON file with HTML/XML entities in the middle. "How decode this to special chars in java" -- I usually pass the string through `Html.fromHtml()`, which decodes most of those.

Comment: That is no ASCII code. Those are XML &-Escapes.

Answer (score 1):

That is "âmbito da Comemoração do Dia de São Valentim, 14 de fevereiro."

```
    String s = "&#226;mbito da Comemora&#231;&#227;o do Dia de S&#227;o Valentim, 14 de fevereiro.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&#(\\d+);|.");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher m  = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        if (m.group(1) != null)
            sb.append((char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
        else
            sb.append(m.group());
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    // -> âmbito da Comemoração do Dia de São Valentim, 14 de fevereiro.
```