# how to generate random alpha numeric with special symbols in Java selenium WD

Tags: java, random, selenium-webdriver, passwords

I am looking for a random alpha-numeric with special symbols password generator for automating a web application where i need to create new password every time the scenario is executed. For example, a generated string of length 9 might look something like "ZgFd123$#"

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string).
Or you can user Java Random() and [Character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-a-string-of-the-associated-character) from 33 to 126.
Example:

```
Random random = new Random();
String str="";
for (int i=0; i<9;i++){
    str += Character.toString(random(93)+33);
}
```