# Converting a user inputted integer to the character with that ASCII code

Tags: java

This is my first post. I also just started. We are supposed to use method calling to get an integer from the user and then use the value inputted in another method and convert it into a ASCII character. This is what I have -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(
            "*** You will enter values in the range of 33-126 for the whole numbers and 33.0-126.0 for the real numbers***");

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("The number is " + getWholeNumber() + 
                       " and the character for this is a(n) " + printCharacter());
}

public static int getWholeNumber() {
    int getWholeNumber;
    System.out.println("Enter a whole number, one that does not have a decimal point: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    getWholeNumber = input.nextInt();
    return getWholeNumber;
}

public static void printCharacter(int getWholeNumber) {
    char letter = (char) getWholeNumber();
    System.out.println(letter);
}
```

I have successfully called the method and displayed the wholenumber but cannot seem to figure out how to convert that to the ASCII character represented by the number.

Comment: If you are allowed to use class `java.lang.Character` then see method [toString(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int))

Comment: Does this help? [How to convert ASCII code (0-255) to its corresponding character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693994/how-to-convert-ascii-code-0-255-to-its-corresponding-character)

Comment: Are you expecting your users to input a single-digit integer?

Comment: I am not sure I know the instructions say I have to call a void method named printCharacter() with exactly one parameter. So thats what I tried to do.

Comment: @ernest_k I am just to assume that they will input a number that is within the listed range of 33-126

Comment: The easiest hack is `System.out.println((int) Integer.toString(getWholeNumber).charAt(0));`, which assumes a single digit was captured by the user.

Comment: Then it's unclear what you're trying to do. Are you getting a digit that you want to print the ASCII code of? Or are you getting an ASCII code to print the corresponding character of?

Comment: I am trying to take the getWholeNumber variable and turn it into ASCII.

Comment: @ernest_k look at the accepted range - 33 to 126 - which are the ASCII codes for all the printable, non-whitespace characters. Obviously the user enters an ASCII code and the program prints the character that has that ASCII code.

Comment: Then please edit your post. Your description and title say the opposite of what you actually want. All you need to do is change the statements `char letter = (char) getWholeNumber();` to `char letter = (char) getWholeNumber;` (use the parameter rather than asking for input again). Also, your main method should send the parameter: `int wholeNumber = getWholeNumber(); System.out.println("The number is " + wholeNumber + " and the character for this is a(n) " + printCharacter(wholeNumber));`

Comment: I am not allowed to have a variable named wholeNumber. I have very specific instructions. I have these two methods getWholeNumber, and printCharacter. The getWholeNumber  method is allowed no parameters, and the printCharacter Method is allowed one parameter getWholeNumber. I have to call both of these methods in the `System.out.println("The number is " + getWholeNumber(); + " and the character for this is a(n) " + printCharacter());` it has to look exactly like that. I am stuck on the printCharacter method and how to correctly call the method that will output an ASCII character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you must convert `int` to `char`. Then use `Character.toString(c)` to get ASCII value of the code:

```
public static void showAsciiCode(int code) {
    char c = (char)code;
    String ascii = Character.toString(c);
    System.out.println("code=" + code + "; char=" + ascii);
}
```

Output:

```
code=33; char=!
code=34; char="
code=35; char=#
code=36; char=$
...
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was struggling to figure out. The only problem is I still am not sure how to call the method without it returning an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you first convert the int to a char, you will have your ascii code.

For example:

```
int iAsciiValue = 9; // Currently just the number 9, but we want 
 //Tab character
// Put the tab character into a string
String strAsciiTab = Character.toString((char) iAsciiValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some problem with your code:

1. Do not use the same name for the method and for the variable. You
   have method `getWholeNumber` and variable with the same name. For variable use
   other name like `result`.
2. When you write `" and the character for this is a(n) " + printCharacter());` you call `printCharacter()` method, but this
   method do not return any value. In its body you have already printed
   result, so I changed this method to `getCharacter()`

Changed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class ascii {

    public static int getWholeNumber() {
        int result;
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number, one that does not have a decimal point: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        result = input.nextInt();
        return result;
    }

    public static char getCharacter(int code) {
        char letter = (char) code;
        return letter;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** You will enter values in the range of 33-126 for the whole numbers and 33.0-126.0 for the real numbers***");
        System.out.println("");
        int code = getWholeNumber();
        char ascii = getCharacter(code);
        System.out.println("The number is " + code + " and the character for this is a(n) " + ascii);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have to print letter from `printCharacter()` method then you can write code like:

```
    public static void printCharacter(int code) {
        char letter = (char) code;
        System.out.println(letter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*** You will enter values in the range of 33-126 for the whole numbers and 33.0-126.0 for the real numbers***");
        System.out.println("");
        int code = getWholeNumber();
        System.out.print("The number is " + code + " and the character for this is a(n) ");
        printCharacter(code);
    }
```

Comment: I honestly would do this if I could but the printCharacter method has too be void. Its the reason I am struggling so much I have no freedom to write the code any way other than what my teacher perceives as correct for this assignment.

Comment: I edited answer with printing letter from `printCharacter()` method.